# su misbehaves when executing a command that prompts for a password

Tags: linux, debian, su

I have 2 users in my debian server, `gooduser` and `root`.

Command `my_cmd` prompts for a password (it connects to a ssh server).

When I execute `my_cmd` as `gooduser`, everything works as expected:

```
gooduser@debian:/mydir$ my_cmd
someone@192.168.2.122's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
someone@192.168.2.122's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
someone@192.168.2.122's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
gooduser@debian:/mydir$
```

Above, I have ignored the password prompts by pressing enter three times. Why, I will tell you soon.

When I am logged in as `root`, however, I try to execute `my_cmd` as user `gooduser` (I have to, so that any files that are created will be owned by `myuser`). However, it doesn't prompt me for a password, not even once, and it works as if I had pressed enter 3 times,  except I didn't (the "Permission denied" messages are the same as above):

```
root@debian:/mydir# su - gooduser -c "cd $PWD; my_cmd"
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
root@debian:/mydir#
```

Why does this happen? Why does `su` ignore the password prompts? Or, more precisely, why does it seem to press enter on my behalf? More importantly, how can I solve this?

(I know I could configure ssh keys for passwordless login and maybe that's what I'll end up doing, but I would like to know what is the deeper issue here).

Comment: what is $PWD at the time of execution as root? does gooduser have access to that path?

Answer (score 1):

ssh tries to open `/dev/tty` to get the password, but the system doesn't allow a user other than the one currently logged in on the terminal to do that. Because of this ssh can't read the password.

Comment: Why is that, I can run this with standard prompt `su - test -c "ssh test"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `sudo`:

```
sudo -i -u gooduser -H bash -c "cd $PWD; my_cmd"
```

Using this command, I was prompted for my password as expected. `-i` was necessary so that `$PATH` was set up correctly, otherwise my command failed.

As for why `su` fails, I still don't know. Using `su` did work in Ubuntu 12.04, but it didn't work in Debian (thus my question), so I'm not sure that qqx's explanation applies.